# Jlist selectedValue is null

Tags: java, jlist

I'm a bit confused with the mechanincs of selection on a JList. Let's say I have a JPanel in a JFrame. Inside this Panel I have a JList and a TextField. If I click on an item of the JList, the item selected goes to light blue colour and a dark blue frame is created around it. At this point, if I call getSelectedValue() I get the selected it correctly. However, if I now click on the TextField, the dark blue frames goes away (the blue "highlight" remains), and if I call getSelectedValue() I get null.

Why does this happens? How can I get the item that is "highlighted" even if it doesn't have the focus (the frame I was talking about)?

Thanks in advance

Edit: It seems the problem is not what I explain. Still, I'm getting a null selected object if I try to get it when pressing a button. Capture:

[image]

Comment: If you don't get a decent correct answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that shows your problem. They say that a small running program that demonstrates the problem is worth a thousand words.

Comment: That's not what I observe. There must be something wrong in your code. Post an SSCCE.

Comment: Same here. If the list has a selection, calling `getSelectedValue()` is most definitely **not** null, even if the JList doesn't have focus.

Comment: Indeed, I just built an example and it works there. That's so weird. Look at the edit

Comment: I think the question here is, under what circumpstances can a JList return null as the selected value when there is a selected value?

Comment: We don't need a capture. We need some Java code. An SSCCE. BTW, your screenshot shows code of a ListSelectionEvent listener. Nothing to do with a button pressed.

Comment: found the problem. Answered myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That add button was triggering a method in which the list was emptied and refilled with the new values. Apparetnly that changes aren't showed even if you are debugging, which is why I was ignoring it and why the screenshot was showing that.